# How to use SortOrder in magento 2 xml files?

Tags: xml

I was studying the construction of the checkout_index_index file on the checkout page, and I realized that there is no way to move an element using the "move element". But it is possible to order an order in which it appears using ordering. However, when I use sort order to move some elements. Payment methods disappear. Then I ask, How is it used correctly? can I place a sort order anywhere inside the "item"? should I put where?.

```
 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like:

```
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
```

app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">21</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: If I copy all the contents of checkout_index_index and put it in my theme folder, and just add the "sortorder", it stops working some things. But if I add it like that it works. Why does this happen?